# 5 tables, scan first to find single match in 1st relational pair or 2nd relational pair without full table scans

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I am still learning mysql and am not even sure how to phrase this to find the answer in a search.

I have 5 tables (actually more, but for the example, 5 suffices), one is the main table, T, and then we have T1 and T2 and their respective relational tables T1_x_T and T2_x_T. I need to go through every row in T to find if there is a match in either T1 or T2 with a given attribute, it only needs to match once, but can have multiple matches. Table structure is something like:

```
T.id
T1.id T1.attrib
T2.id T2.attrib
T1_x_T.T1_id, T1_x_T.T_id
T2_x_T.T2_id, T2_x_T.T_id
```

If the entry in T has a match in either T1 or T2 on that attrib something like:

```
 (T.id = T1_x_T.T_id and T1.id = T1_x_T.T1_id and T1.attrib = SOMEVAL) or (T.id = T2_x_T.T_id and T2.id = T2_x_T.T2_id and T2.attrib = SOMEVAL)
```

Ie, as soon as it finds a match for T, move on to the next row in T and don't scan the rest of the table nor move to the next table. Basically to answer the question: "For each id in T, is there *any* match in T1_x_T or T2_x_T where the corresponding T1 or T2 value matches a given value for attrib?"

So the result would be a subset of table T.

My initial intuition is to use `LEFT INNER JOIN`, `LIMIT` and `GROUP BY` to achieve this, but I don't know enough about either (or mysql) to know how to accomplish this or if it is accomplishable. I do know how to do this in what I assume is the inefficient way (full table scans for both?) or in two queries and then parse the results outside of mysql, but I want to learn how to build nice efficient queries.

---

Sample data, as requested, for query where attrib = 1:

```
T.id:
i1
i2
i3

T1.id - T1.attrib:
a     - 1
b     - 0

T1_x_T.T1_id -  T1_x_T.T_id:
a            -  i1
b            -  i1
b            -  i2


T2.id - T2.attrib:
y     - 0
z     - 1

T2_x_T.T2_id -  T2_x_T.T_id:
z            -  i3
y            -  i2
```

Results in:

```
i1
i3
```

Since T1.id = a has T1.attrib = 1 and T1_x_T.T1_id = a has entry with T1_x_T.T_id = i1; and T2.id = z has T2.attrib = 1 and T2_x_T.T2_id = a has entry with T2_x_T.T_id = i3.

Hope that helps explain a bit.

Comment: Please show us tables with sample data and expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen edited as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
T.id as T_id
FROM T
LEFT JOIN T1_x_T ON T.id= T1_x_T.T_id
LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.id = T1_x_T.T1_id
LEFT JOIN T2_x_T ON T.id= T2_x_T.T_id
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.id = T2_x_T.T2_id
WHERE T1.attributes = '1' OR  T2.attribute = '1';
```

Well this maps your question:

> "For each id in T, is there any match in T1_x_T or T2_x_T where the
>   corresponding T1 or T2 value matches a given value for attrib?"

and provide your expected result in the example.

Just to clarify how things work.

LEFT JOINS combine all the rows following the ON clause like T.id = T1_x_T.T_id. If the join find n different T and m different records in T1_x_T that respect the ON clause, it will produce a m x n result with al the possible values.

So here is the result of the joins in your case:

[image]

Where you see NULL is what you mean with short circuit, there is no match, so no result.

When you put the WHERE or the GROUP BY you are acting on this extended table result of JOIN to put your conditions.

By the way, when you are trying a complex join it can be a good idea to look the complete results to better understand if you are doing it right and select the appropriate conditions to obtain the desired result.

Regards

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I had to add a GROUP BY to remove duplicates, but otherwise your approach worked a charm. Can you confirm whether this is the most efficient way to do this? Ie, would the scan stop after all rows in T have been scanned? And does it short-circuit after the first positive match in either table?

Comment: LEFT JOIN is driven by the rows of the first left table, in this case T. Maybe scanned is not the most appropriate term, as it is not a sequential process, but the concept is that. Look my update.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is quite efficient.

Comment: But is it the _most_ efficient way? The reason I ask is because I want to be able to expand the number of tables included in the query, so, say, a T3, T4.. and I want to avoid those extra tables from being scanned unless absolutely necessary, ie, this is what I mean by "short-circuit", that is "stop scanning stuff once you have your desired results".

Comment: JOINS will combine all the tables and then cut down. About efficiency I can only say that UNION is a much more expensive mechanism. Relational DB works with SET algebra not sequential scan, which is beneficial in this case. If you tried to do the same with a procedural language you would get very long loops.

Comment: Awesome, great, that was the answer I was looking for. I just confirmed on a really small dataset that the LEFT JOIN is almost twice as fast as the INNER JOIN + UNION. When comparing both having added a GROUP BY clause. Thanks again. (If you edit your answer to include the GROUP BY I believe this will be the accepted answer, unless someone else adds another that is more correct/efficient).

Comment: Ah, nevermind, spoke too soon, in terms of my dataset they seem to both be running at the same speed. I will have to check again with a larger set. I will report back once this is known.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest indeed the use of `INNER JOIN`, but combined with `UNION`:

```
SELECT     T.id
FROM       T
INNER JOIN T1_x_T
        ON T1_x_T.T_id = T.id
INNER JOIN T1 
        ON T1.id = T1_x_T.T1_id
WHERE      T1.attrib = 1
UNION
SELECT     T.id
FROM       T
INNER JOIN T2_x_T
        ON T2_x_T.T_id = T.id
INNER JOIN T2 
        ON T2.id = T2_x_T.T2_id
WHERE      T2.attrib = 1
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f46c7/1).

As your condition concerns the columns of the joined tables, you should not use outer joins like `LEFT JOIN` in this case. Although the output would be the same, `LEFT JOIN` is generally more expensive in terms of performance.

The `UNION` clause will also make sure you don't get duplicates.

Also, if you are only interested in the *id* value of table *T*, then you don't need to include that table at all in the query, and this would be better:

```
SELECT     T1_x_T.T_id
FROM       T1_x_T
INNER JOIN T1 
        ON T1.id = T1_x_T.T1_id
WHERE      T1.attrib = 1
UNION
SELECT     T2_x_T.T_id
FROM       T2_x_T
INNER JOIN T2 
        ON T2.id = T2_x_T.T2_id
WHERE      T2.attrib = 1
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f46c7/2)

You might also compare the performance with this alternative, which performs sub queries. One might expect it will skip the second one if the first one gives a match, but as this may differ per *id* value, there really is no gain: both sub queries will be executed first before the matchings with the *id* values are done. There a short-cicuit will take place, but only for the comparison with the already generated result sets:

```
SELECT id
FROM   T
WHERE  id IN (
          SELECT     T1_x_T.T_id
          FROM       T1_x_T
          INNER JOIN T1 
                  ON T1.id = T1_x_T.T1_id
          WHERE      T1.attrib = 1)
    OR id IN ( 
          SELECT     T2_x_T.T_id
          FROM       T2_x_T
          INNER JOIN T2 
                  ON T2.id = T2_x_T.T2_id
          WHERE      T2.attrib = 1)
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f46c7/3)

One could potentially force the short-circuit with correlated sub queries, but then such sub query has to be executed again and again for each *id*. And even though in some cases it would not have to repeat that for the second sub query, the loss in performance, due to the repeated executions for different *id* values, will be much greater than the gain from the short-circuit evaluation. Also the execution plan might see an optimisation and thus not follow the produce I just described:

```
SELECT id
FROM   T
WHERE  EXISTS (
          SELECT     1
          FROM       T1_x_T
          INNER JOIN T1 
                  ON T1.id = T1_x_T.T1_id
          WHERE      T1.attrib = 1
          AND        T1.id = T.id)
    OR EXISTS ( 
          SELECT     1
          FROM       T2_x_T
          INNER JOIN T2 
                  ON T2.id = T2_x_T.T2_id
          WHERE      T2.attrib = 1
          AND        T2.id = T.id)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, the first one was (except for the WHERE clause, in which I used OR) almost exactly the approach I was taking, but like in mine, this returns the empty set for some reason. Let me try the second one and report back. Quick question, I thought that by using the T table it would actually increase performance by reducing the number of rows scanned, since T is way shorter than either of T1 or T2, and once T is done, the query completes, whereas without it, wouldn't it have to scan both T1 and T2?

Comment: I can confirm that the second query returns the expected set btw.

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer, fixing the first SQL. It should be a UNION also. The wrong version wants all conditions to be true at once, but since i1 <> i3, that excludes all results. I added SQL fiddle links as well (works if it is not overloaded).

Comment: So in terms of efficiency, does the use of UNION force a scan of the second table? Does it stop after all rows in T have matched in the left side of the union?

Comment: It depends on the execution plan, which depends on indexes and other logic that MySql might apply based on tables sizes, etc. I added another alternative that I think would short-circuit if possible, although it might suffer performance loss for other reasons.

Comment: Added another alternative again. I would be interested to hear from you concernging the performance of these queries on your data.